# autohide an element in VueJS after 1 second

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, settimeout, vue-cli

OK, so I'm new to Vue ( basically, new to JS in general, but I'm playing with Vue right now ) and what I want to do, is to auto hide an element ( not on click ) inside the template tag of a component. In jQuery this would look like:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".hideElement").hide()
    }, 1000);
});
```

but how this works in Vue? my component looks like this:

```
<template>
<div>
 <h1 class="hideElement"> HELLO </h1>
</div>
</template>

<script> // nothing here 
</script>

<style> // nothing here
</style>
```

I know how to toggle the element on click of a button, but I just want to auto hide it after 1 second without any click events everytime the users enter this component ( which is a new "page" )

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could just add a property in the data object and use v-show directive to determine whether the element should be visible or not. If the boolean is false the element is hidden, if true the element is visible.

Method Created called synchronously after the instance is created.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 v-show="elementVisible" class="hideElement"> HELLO </h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                elementVisible: true
            }
        },

        created() {
            setTimeout(() => this.elementVisible = false, 1000)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: With ESlint you will get "Arrow function should not return assignment". You have to use a function with the body cause you are not returning a value with the arrow function. So you should write something like: ```setTimeout(() => { this.elementVisible = false }, 1000)```